# Why is my insert_node function erasing my root? (C)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, inorder

I'm trying to write a program that inserts nodes with member strings into a BST then prints information about that BST such as height, an inorder traversal, number of leaves, etc...

As of right now, when I do an inorder traversal it prints the last string being entered as the root, even if it should be at the bottom of the tree.

Here's the code:

insert function:

```
void insert_node(Node* root, char *nextString) {
    int newLessThanRoot = strcmp( root->Word, nextString ) > 0 ? 1 : 0; // test if nextString is left or right from root

    if (newLessThanRoot && root->Left != NULL) {
      return insert_node(root->Left, nextString);
    }
    if (!newLessThanRoot && root->Right != NULL) {
      return insert_node(root->Right, nextString);
    }

    Node* freshNode = newNode();
    freshNode->Word = malloc(strlen(nextString) +1);
    strcpy(freshNode->Word, nextString);
    freshNode->Left = NULL;
    freshNode->Right = NULL;

    if (newLessThanRoot) {
      root->Left = freshNode;
    }
    else {
      root->Right = freshNode;
    }
}
```

inorder traversal function:

```
void inorder(Node *temp) {
  if (temp != NULL) {
    inorder(temp->Left);
    printf("%s ",temp->Word);
    inorder(temp->Right);
  }
}
```

How they're being used:

```
 char inputString[15];
  char *inputStringPtr = &inputString[0];
  Node* root;
  root = newNode();
  fscanf(infile,"%s",inputStringPtr);
  root->Word = inputString;
  //printf("Root's word: %s\n",root->Word);

  while (fscanf(infile,"%s",inputStringPtr) == 1) {
      insert_node(root,inputStringPtr);
      printf("%s\n",inputString);
  }

  int numberOfStrings = num_of_strings(root);
  int heightOfBST = height_of_tree(root);
  int numberOfLeaves = num_of_leaves(root);

  inorder(root);
```

The input looks like this:

```
b a c e d l m n o p z
```

so the output (when doing inorder traversal) should be:

```
a b c d e l m n o p z
```

but instead it's:

```
z a c d e l m n o p z
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you read the value of the root node:

```
root = newNode();
fscanf(infile,"%s",inputStringPtr);
root->Word = inputString;
```

and here, you overwrite it again with the value of the second node:

```
while (fscanf(infile,"%s",inputStringPtr) == 1) {
```

You could use strdup() to make a copy of the root value:

```
root->Word = strdup(inputString);
```

This should fix your problem.

In `insert_node()` you correctly copy the value for each new node. You might consider to use `strdup()` there, too, instead of malloc(strlen())/strcpy().

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with your inOrder function and insert_node function. The usage has some issues. In the line

```
 root->Word = inputString;
```

you are assigning the local store address to root. As local store continues to change, the root Word also changes.

Comment: Ahhh, Thank you very much, fixing that line worked, thanks a ton.